# Mensa IQ app: four boxes with four numbers each

Tags: mathematics, pattern

Stuck trying to solve this question that popped up the other day. Spent the whole of the 15 minute test trying to find an answer to it. [image: Iq question]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer is

> $2$

because

> in each box, label the numbers like this:
>
> `A B`
>  `C D`
>
> Then $B * C = 10A + D$.
>
> i.e. $3 * 6 = 18$, $7 * 8 = 56$, and $9 * 3 = 27$. So in the final box, we need a $2$ to complete the equation $5 * 4 = 20$.

Answer (score 5):

I hate this kind of puzzles, since the solution always feels kind of arbitrary to me. Just for the sake of it I suggest an alternative solution:

> 1

Reason:

> The four boxes form a table with four rows and four columns. In each column, label the numbers like this:
>
>  A
>
>  B
>
>  C
>
>  D
>
>  Then (A+B+C+D) mod 3 = 0

Now that I think about it, using the same argument, even

> 7

would be a solution. Depending on your creativity, it appears to me that any given number might be a solution to this problem.